# Переход по ссылке только для авторизованных пользователей Laravel

Tags: laravel

есть такая задача  на laravel, есть ссылка (роут), при переходе по ней авторизованному пользователю он переходит по ней без проблем и срабатывает метод, но как сделать так если пользователь не авторизован в системе, то чтобы при переходе по этой ссылке, он сначала авторизовывался, а потом автоматически перенаправлялся по этой ссылке обратно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете стандартную ui:auth то можете добавить к роуту "middleware auth"

Пример

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth');
```